# Bash script in EC2 fails due to permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am not quite experienced with EC2 and want to setup a cron job to create a dump of my RDS's database and copy it into my S3 bucket.

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***
BUCKET=db-snapshots

MYSQL_USER=***
MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
MYSQL_HOST=***
MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME= 'database_name'

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S")

#logging
LOG_ROOT="/backup/mysql_dump/logs/dump.log"

#Dump of Mysql Database into S3
echo "[db-take-snapshot]: creating backup of database $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME start at $TSTAMP" >> "$LOG_ROOT"

mysqldump -u $MYSQL_USER \
          -p $MYSQL_PASSWORD \
          -h $MYSQL_HOST \
          --single-transaction \
          --routines --triggers \
          --database_name  $MYSQL_DATABASES_NAME| gzip > backup.gz

echo "[db-take-snapshot]:Finished backup of database and sending it in S3 Bucket at $TIMESTAMP" >> "$LOG_ROOT"

S3_KEY=$BUCKET/backups/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")-backup.gz
aws s3 cp backup.gz s3://$S3_KEY --sse AES256

echo "[db-take-snapshot]: Copied to S3 at $TIMESTAMP" >> "$LOG_ROOT"

rm -f backup.gz

echo "[db-take-snapshot]: Backup finished at $TIMESTAMP" >> "$LOG_ROOT"
```

Deactivating the logging part at the moment and the script above fails due to permissions:

```
/db-take-snapshot-s3.sh: line 25: backup.gz: Permission denied
```

The permissions are: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1144 Mar 21 10:30 db-take-snapshot-s3.sh`

Any ideas would be highly appreciated

**Update:**

`$ll -d . : drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 21 11:07 .`

`$ll: -rwx------ 1 root root 1139 Mar 21 11:06 db-take-snapshot-s3.sh`

`$pwd: /etc/cron.hourly`

`id: uid=500(ec2-user) gid=500(ec2-user) groups=500(ec2-user),10(wheel)`

**UPDATE 2** 
Okay, I ran `mysqldump -h $MYSQL_HOST  -u $MYSQL_USER -p $MYSQL_PASSWORD --all-databases > backup.sql` in my terminal and the backup is taken successfully.

However, it still fails as part of the bash script and the content of the produced backup.sql is now:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issues of EC2, S3 and RDS are a distraction at the moment, basically RDS is just like any mysql instance and EC2 is just like any linux VM. It seems you're not even getting to the point of worrying about S3 yet (although that bit looks fine).

You should run your backup script as a non-root user, so move it to `/home/ec2-user` for now.

Then, you should run the cron under ec2-user - use `sudo -u ec2-user crontab -e` to edit ec2-user's crontab - don't go editing crontab's directly on a modern distro.

That will solve the backup.gz issue but you will also need to ensure `$MYSQL_USER`@`ec2_ip` is a valid user on your RDS instance. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198367/creating-a-new-mysql-user-in-amazon-rds-environment) answer might be informative.

Edit: Your latest problem probably just means you need to change from -u $MYSQL_USER to -u$MYSQL_USER for example - and the same for the host and password params.

Comment: Thanks @maarghk!
Moved the script under `/home/ec2-user` and running the cron as ec2-user.
Right now, I am using the RDS' MySQL user to connect from my EC2 instance (using EC2 and RDS just to clarify which box I am trying to connect from/to).

What am I missing here? :)

Comment: Could you update the question with any new errors?

Comment: @maarghk Updated my question.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Fixed- I dropped the space between -p and "password".

Thanks for you help @maarghk. Appreciated!

Comment: no worries. feel free to accept it as the solution if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This fault is not related to rights of the script file itself (*db-take-snapshot-s3.sh*) but rather to rights of directory where the script is run and temporarily saves file *backup*.gz.

I recommend you to list rights of directory where you run a script

```
ll -d .
```

And also add write permission to that directory

```
chmod +w .
```

It is also important if it won't work to mention these info (current directory and current user) so we can help more.

```
id
pwd
ll
ll -d .
```

Comment: Question updated, @Koss645